# When can my edited question finally be released from the "on hold status"

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

I edited [my question](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/491/what-methods-are-there-to-learn-the-ancient-languages-aramaic-as-an-example) within less then 24h after it was put on hold. But instead of "releasing" it people seem not even have realized that it has been re-edited and some keep down-voting it. The question is/was valid as far as I could tell and it is even briefly well answered.

I know we still have no mods yet, but it would be nice if a re-open request would start.

Of course if there should be an other "close-reason" or reason to put it on hold I'd be glad to know about it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Despite editing your question, as it stands now, the title still reads:

> What methods are there to learn the ancient languages (Aramaic as an example)?

[user3169](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/users/106/user3169) had a valid point when he [commented](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/491/what-methods-are-there-to-learn-the-ancient-languages-aramaic-as-an-example#comment912_491):

> ...you should start with just one language that would be the best example. If the techniques between languages are not the same, each should be asked in a separate question.

*"the ancient languages"* is very broad, covering many, many, many languages, while leaving the definition of "ancient" unclear.

---

A more focused version of your question could be as follows:

> What methods are there to learn Aramaic?

(focusing on one language)

or

> How does one find resources to learn a dead language?

(focusing on *finding resources to learn a dead language*, not *methods to learn the ancient languages*, however, this might be POB or too broad)

or

> How to study a language with texts only?

(how to learn a language based on writings only)

Comment: Thanks for the helpful and constructive hints i tried to adapt them, without deviating from my main point of interest.

Comment: The question has now been reformulated to focus on learning vocabulary. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

Summarizing the problem, you are trying to capture a significant portion of this site's scope in the space of *one* post. Stack Exchange is not a good platform for pedagogy. *"How do people learn [ancient] language?"* is way too broad to be aptly and concisely answered in this format.

If you had a very *specific* problem involving an obstacle you were trying to overcome because you were in the process of learning an **ancient** language, that might present an interesting challenge.

> E.g. "How can I employ specific-listening-technique {x} if the language is no longer being spoken?"

But the inherently-early starting point of your question is simply too broad for this type of Q&A.

Comment: I do agree that in some cases the point or rule of "focused question" on SE seems to me very hard. As people usually ask either because they are curious about something or have an actual problem in the first case to elaborate a focused question is more difficult, so that's IMO the point where comments of the community might be helpful. In my job i often deal with new things so i try to find any helpful information and pic later so even there asking a focused question is difficult. I honestly only wanted to know how learning such a language is possible and got my answer.